# Geolocation Clustering

Tags: python-3.x, geolocation, cluster-analysis

I am trying to cluster points to the nearest neighbor. I have a dataset with population, latitude and longitude. Since clustering works on distance measure and the co ordinates here are geolocations, how do I approach to this problem in python?
. [image]

Comment: https://geoffboeing.com/2014/08/clustering-to-reduce-spatial-data-set-size/

Answer (score 0):

You can go with [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) clustering from scipy library. Based on distance, minimum number of samples and other parameters, it creates clusters.

I have applied it successfully to geolocations, although first I converted coordinates to metric coordinate system.

Comment: How do I convert coordinates to metric system?

Comment: The easiest way would be to create `GeoDataFrame` with the use of [`geopandas`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) and then use its [`to_crs`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html) function. You have to find which UTM zone your data is in, for instance [here](https://mangomap.com/robertyoung/maps/69585/what-utm-zone-am-i-in-#) or maybe there is a local coordinate system you can use. You have to know its `EPSG` code.

Answer (score 0):

I have datasets with geographical grids of 1 degree X 1 degree (same distance for each point) and have some value over them. I am planning to apply DBSCAN by using 3rd variable as weight.

Comment: Please consider providing some source code to support the given answer explaining show how it solves the problem.